# Using C to output a key on a web page

Tags: c, web

Is there any way I can use ANSI C to output words onto a web page? Or if I'm completely off, what language (or script) is used to do this sort of stuff?

I wanna try this since I just found a website (virtualpiano), and now I want to make some kind of programming that can read out the "notes" and play it on the virtual piano.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: "and now I want to make some kind of programming that can read out the "notes"", presumably "notes" are stored in some sort of text format? I would probably purely use Js.

Comment: That sounds like a quite interesting project! If you allow me a recommendation, take a look at the [Greasemonkey extension](https://www.greasespot.net/) to implement it with JavaScript. Here is a [tutorial](http://hayageek.com/greasemonkey-tutorial/), and a [list of tutorials](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Tutorials) here.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably look at JavaScript instead. You *can* write C programs that are run on the web server, and the output from the C program will be the text of the web page, but that is not a very modern way of doing it, and for a thing like a virtual piano you need to run the program on the client, i. e. in the user's web browser, and then JavaScript will be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript should have been a better option for you, maybe you might want to check [Soundslice](https://www.soundslice.com/scores/auld-lang-syne/), this have something similar to what you need or this SO post [creating sheet music with piano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674834/i-want-to-create-sheet-music-with-piano-using-html-css-and-javascript) or even this github repo [abcjs](https://github.com/paulrosen/abcjs) which gives some close to what you're trying to archive.

I hope this helps.